# あるアプリで撮った写真をiCloudにアップロード/ダウンロードしたい

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

現在は写真を撮ってimageviewに表示するに止まっています。この写真をiCloudにアップして、imageCopyにダウンロードしたいのですが、写真のアップ/ダウンの方法がわかりません。
宜しくお願いいたします。

```
//
// AppDelegate.swift
//
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
        var window: UIWindow? //ウィンドウ

    //アプリ起動完了時に呼ばれる
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
        launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}



コードをここに入力
//
// ViewController.swift
//


import UIKit

//iCloud
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    //定数
    let BTN_WRITE1 = 2 //書き込み1
    let BTN_READ1 = 3  //読み込み1

    //変数
    var _textField1: UITextField! //テキストフィールド1
    var _textField3: UITextField! //テキストフィールド2

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageCopy: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func launchCamera(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let camera = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(camera) {
            let picker = UIImagePickerController()
            picker.sourceType = camera
            picker.delegate = self
            self.present(picker,animated: true)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        self.imageView.image = image
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }


//====================
//UI
//====================
    //ロード完了時に呼ばれる
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let dx: CGFloat = (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width-320)/2


        //ドキュメントのUIの生成
        _textField1 = makeTextField(CGRect(x: dx+10, y: 140, width: 200, height: 32), text: "")
        self.view.addSubview(_textField1)
        let btnWrite1 = makeButton(CGRect(x: dx+10, y: 190, width: 190, height: 40),
            text: "ドキュメントの書き込み", tag: BTN_WRITE1)
        self.view.addSubview(btnWrite1)
        let btnRead1 = makeButton(CGRect(x: dx+210, y: 190, width: 90, height: 40),
            text: "読み込み", tag: BTN_READ1)
        self.view.addSubview(btnRead1)
    }

    //ボタンクリック時に呼ばれる
    func onClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.tag == BTN_WRITE1 {
            DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: {
                let icloudURL = self.makeICloudURL("img_test")
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    if icloudURL != nil {
                        self.writeICloud1(icloudURL!)
                    } else {
                        self.showAlert("エラー", text: "iCloudのURLの取得に失敗")
                    }
                })
            })
        } else if sender.tag == BTN_READ1 {
            DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: {
                let icloudURL = self.makeICloudURL("img_test")
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    if icloudURL != nil {
                        self.readICloud1(icloudURL!)
                    } else {
                        self.showAlert("エラー", text: "iCloudのURLの取得に失敗")
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    }

    //テキストフィールドの初期化
    func makeTextField(_ frame: CGRect, text: String) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.frame = frame
        textField.text = text
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
        textField.delegate = self
        return textField
    }

    //テキストボタンの初期化
    func makeButton(_ frame: CGRect, text: String, tag: Int) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
        button.frame = frame
        button.setTitle(text, for: UIControlState())
        button.tag = tag
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClick(_:)),
            for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        return button
    }

    //アラートの表示
    func showAlert(_ title: String?, text: String?) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: text,
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
            style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

//====================
//iCloud
//====================

    //iCloudのドキュメントのURLの生成(3)
    func makeICloudURL(_ fileName: String) -> URL? {
        //iCloudのディレクトリのURLの生成
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let icloudURL = fileManager.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)
        if let docURL = icloudURL?.appendingPathComponent("Documents") {
            //ディレクトリがない時は生成
            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: docURL.path) == false {
                do {
                    try fileManager.createDirectory(at: docURL,
                        withIntermediateDirectories: true,
                        attributes: nil)
                } catch _ {
                }
            }

            //iCloudのドキュメントのURLを返す
            return docURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        }
        return nil
    }

    //iCloudへのドキュメントの書き込み(4)
    func writeICloud1(_ icloudURL: URL) {
        let document = ICloudDocument(fileURL: icloudURL)

        document.text = _textField1.text!
        document.save(to: icloudURL,
            for: UIDocumentSaveOperation.forCreating,
            completionHandler: {(success: Bool) in
                 print("write document>\(success)")
        })
    }

    //iCloudからのドキュメントの読み込み(5)
    func readICloud1(_ icloudURL: URL) {
        let document = ICloudDocument(fileURL: icloudURL)
        document.open(completionHandler: {(success: Bool) in
            print("read document>\(success)")
            self._textField1.text = document.text
        })
    }

//====================
//UITextFieldDelegate
//====================
    //改行ボタン押下時に呼ばれる
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ sender: UITextField) -> Bool {
        //キーボードを閉じる
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }
}


コードをここに入力
//
// ICloudDocument.swift
//

import UIKit

//ドキュメント
class ICloudDocument: UIDocument {
    var text = "" //テキスト

    //ドキュメント読み込み時に呼ばれる(6)
    override func load(fromContents contents: Any, ofType: String?) throws {
        self.text = (NSString(data: contents as! Data,
                              encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as String?)!
    }

    //ドキュメント書き込み時に呼ばれる(7)
    override func contents(forType typeName: String) throws -> Any {
        if let value = self.text.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            return value
        }
        return Data()
    }
}
```

[image: iCloudの設定]

[image: cameraの設定]

Answer (score 0):

WebAPIのようなものはないか？というご質問でしょうか？

当方iCloudは使用したことがないので、単なるWebCrawlの結果となりますがCloudKitというライブラリがあるようです。
https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit